# No order confirmation when a customer chooses payment method paypal or sofort Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, order-confirmation

We are offering different payment methods like PayPal, credit card, "**sofort**".

When a customer chooses one of these methods, he gets redirected to the payment page but there is **no order confirmation** email beeing send to the customer or the copy to us.

For methods like invoice or bank transfer it works fine. The customer gets confirmation and we get the copy of the confirmation.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue to get send a confirmation email everytime.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

**PayPal** Supports **two type** of Payment Action in Online Payments

**1. Sale:** – If one uses payment action as ‘Sale’ in PayPal online payment, the amount will be automatically credited to merchant account when the order is placed successfully.

If one sets PayPal payment action as ‘Sale’, the order is invoiced automatically when the order is placed. If the PayPal payment method is used as ‘Sale’, you have to set the following settings through Magento backend, and then only product can be downloaded in the case of downloadable products:

> Login to Magento Backend
>       Take System->Configuration
>       Take Catalog->Downloadable Product Options
>       Set ‘Order Item Status to enable Downloads’ to ‘Invoiced’

**2. Authorization:** – The amount is not automatically credited to merchant account when order is placed successfully. For crediting amount to merchant account, the merchant should login to PayPal account and should approve the transaction. The PayPal payment action can be set through Magento backend. For that please do the following actions:

> Login to Magento Backend
>       Take System->Configuration
>       Take Payment Method
>       Select PayPal Website Payments Pro (Pay flow Edition) – Direct Payments

Comment: the first point you mentioned didnt work